# how to call serial objects names in loop?

Tags: java

I want to call 100 object names without need to write their names 100 times
let's say that i have 100 Button named B1, B2, B3...B100
for example i want to set them visible so i need to write

```
B1.setVisible(true);
```

and so on for the rest 99 object
i need to enter them in loop so every turn new object get set visible
i tried `B"i".setVisible(true);` but the IDE did not accept it
i tried `B%.setVisible(true);` but i don't know how to replace the %
important note: the 100 objects already exist
thank you

Comment: Use `java.util.Map` implementation.

Comment: Or use a n array of the objects

Comment: You could put them in an array and loop through the entire array, setting all of them to not Visible

Comment: You have no way to do it like you want

Answer (score 5):

Add the buttons to a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) - you can do that in a loop if the button text and their behavior is similar enough:

```
...
List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
for (int count = 0;  count < 100; count++) {
   Button myButton = new Button("b" + count);
   buttons.add(myButton);
}
...
```

Then, you can iterate over the list and access all the buttons:

```
...
for (Button b : buttons) {
   b.setVisible(true);
}
...
```

Comment: so i have to add 100 button!
the same problem

Comment: You **have** to create them at some place - usually buttons have some specific behaviour attached and some unique text assigned, but if the buttons are similar enough you can of course also create them in a loop.

Comment: So you already have 100 fields of `Button` which are called `b1`, `b2`, `b3`, ...? In that case, you should consider refactoring that code. Otherwise, reflection as proposed by @Walfrat is indeed the only possibility. In an case, you should add the fact that these fields already exist to your question.

Comment: In fact if you have legacy code, just say you have **legacy code**, we all know what it means and will answer more accuretly.

Comment: no it's not legacy code just need to add event on mouse click to hide some objects but i don not want to write all of objects names individually

Answer (score 2):

If they're a part of an object you can  use reflection. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/fields.html

Performance wise it's not the best, but if you have a legacy app where you need this you probably have way worst than this in.

Here is what will look like a code that will match you need.

```
MyObject objectInstance = new MyObject();
Class  aClass = MyObject.class
for(int i = 1; i <=100; i++){
    Field field = aClass.getField("B"+i);
    // get the value
    Object value = (Button)field.get(objectInstance);
    // set the value 
   field.set(objetInstance, value);
}
```